# append element to array

Tags: python, arrays

I received error while appending element to an array.

```
array([[ 5,  89,  342,  282,    3,  644, 1254,  634,    4,  711,   58,
        1554,  23,  613,  565,    2,  787,  968,  640,    7,  676,  65,
         346]])
```

I want to append mean of this array 3 times to this array so if the mean is 10, "10, 10, 10" will be added to the array.

```
mean = array.mean()
array= array.append(mean, mean, mean)
```

error message

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Where did I do wrong ? thank you

Comment: `append` as you are using it, is meant for lists. Perhaps you want [`numpy.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)?

Comment: sharing the full code would also be of huge help

Comment: @DavidG thanks. if i used np.append I got another error message 'append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values''

Comment: @JanNeduchal This is the full code already

Comment: it obviously isnt if the interpreter is saying there was a problem with a numpy object (where is the import?)

Comment: @JanNeduchal aww yes sorry i missed import. I did import numpy firstly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like this.

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[ 5,  89,  342,  282,    3,  644, 1254,  634,    4,  711,   58,
        1554,  23,  613,  565,    2,  787,  968,  640,    7,  676,  65,
         346]])

mean = array.mean()

new_array = np.append(array,np.array([mean,mean,mean]))
```

Comment: works well on testing.  Out of curiousity - do you know why this works using numpy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are meaning. I know each object has its own methods. 'numpy' is an object 'array' is another object too. Append is a method for 'numpy' not for 'array'.

Comment: Because array is a mutable object ?

Comment: I'm confusing append on a list with append on an array - just getting up to scratch on numpy.  That helps some - thanks!

Comment: @takkyi83  I think this is true. if  you refer to this [address](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/genindex.html) you will find some function are "(numpy.ndarray method)". these function can be used as method of 'array' object. but some of them like 'append' are just "(in module numpy)". so the second one can be available for 'numpy' objects.